# Animations about a young man pulled into a fantasy setting with dragons?

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for an animation (more likely a film not a series) that I watched as a kid, watched early 90's I'm sure it contained a book loving male main character (wears glasses might have even had an amulet) who gets pulled into a fantasy via a magic book

Setting with dragons and an evil wizard, I remember it being on TV as I never had it on VHS.

Same sort of animation technique as visionaries or thundercats.

Thanks.

Comment: We don't know when you were a kid...a timeframe would be useful.

Comment: Is there anything else you remember? How the characters looked, specific scenes?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Sounds like [*Flight of Dragons*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Flight_of_Dragons) to me.

A former scientist designs a board game where the characters are unknowingly real. He's sucked into the magical world to stop the evil wizard called Ommadon.

[image: Peter in his shop with the pieces of his game]

Screenshot of Peter from [followingthenerd](http://www.followingthenerd.com/ftn_news/the-flight-of-dragons-to-be-made-into-live-action-film/#sthash.7GnXkZzl.dpbs).

I believe the amulet you're thinking of was left with him as a reminder of his experience in the magical world.

Comment: Yes the amulet was a shield it turns out, thanks :)

Comment: @JamesD the amulet comment was really bugging me - I knew there was a locket or someing in it but it's been about 20 years since I watched it. My memory isn't that good!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe its "The never ending story"

Comment: This question was already answered, see above. As a guide or answering future questions, please don't post one line answers - provide an explanation for *why* you think that this is the answer. You should check out our [tour], as well. Hope to see you around!

Comment: For what it's worth, it is perfectly valid to post an answer that matches the question, even if there is an upvoted answer, *even if there is an accepted answer* because it will help other people who might be looking for that work, but it really does require more than "it might be this". You need to indicate what details match (and which do not).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/97709)

Comment: @DBPriGuy - I’d say it is an answer, albeit a very brief one. It could certainly use a bit more detail, though.

Comment: @Adamant: Looking back, I agree.